# How can I graph this data using python?

Tags: python, database, graph

I've been keeping a list of all the films I've been watching and the date I watched those films in the format DD/MM/YYYY, using a simple program I made.
I'd like to now graph this data with the number of films watched on the Y axis and the date on the X axis.
Using python, how should I go about doing this, any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You should post a sample of your data. We have no idea if you're storing the data as json, csv, pandas DataFrame etc.

Comment: If you want to graph the number of films you have watched per day you can do a simple `.groupby` on the dataframe.

Comment: My data is in the form of a list of strings (laid out like this DD/MM/YYYY) in a text file.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I haven't tried anything yet I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: What if you start by googling "How to read data from a database using Python"? That will give you a first approach.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you have a data frame named `df` like this:

```
    movie_name  watch_date
0   movie1      01/05/2020
1   movie2      01/05/2020
2   movie3      02/05/2020
.   .           .
.   .           .
.   .           .
```

You can make a new data frame by:

```
df_new = df.groupby('watch_date').count()
```

By writing code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Count')
sns.scatterplot(x='watch_date', y='movie_name', data=df_new, color='red')
plt.yticks(range(6))
```

Output will be:

[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Goz.png)